# How to resolve linkage error in java unit tests when using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Tags: java, lucene, powermock, linkageerror

I use lucene version 3.5.0 in a project and use PowerMockRunner in some unit tests to mock static methods. Now I want to upgrade lucene to version 3.6.2 but I get a linkage error when executing the unit tests that run with the PowerMockRunner.

I think it has to do with conflicting class loaders but I don't know how to resolve this problem. And I wonder why it worked with lucene 3.5.0. Any hints are welcome!

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(Ljavax/management/MBeanServerConnection;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/lucene/util/RamUsageEstimator, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, java/lang/management/ManagementFactory, have different Class objects for the type avax/management/MBeanServerConnection;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; used in the signature
at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator.<clinit>(RamUsageEstimator.java:225)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder$UnCompiledNode.addArc(Builder.java:552)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.add(Builder.java:376)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymMap$Builder.build(SynonymMap.java:314)
at my.package.BaseformAnalyzerTest.createSynonymMap(BaseformAnalyzerTest.java:69)
at my.package.BaseformAnalyzerTest.setUp(BaseformAnalyzerTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to ClassLoader conflict. Don't allow mock classloader to load javax.management.*

Add a class level annotation `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")` to solve this

Comment: When you want to give *multiple* of those statements, you have to put them into a String array: `@PowerMockIgnore( { "first.ignore.package.*" , "second.ignore.package.*" } )`